# Http status code when creating resource but child reference missing

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

consider the following resources

-Year

-Classroom

-Students

I create a new resource with next URIs related to

> PUT /years/{year Es: 2108}
>
> PUT /classrooms/{classroom code Es: ls1sa, ls2sa, ls3sa...}
>
> POST /students

A student for a specific year belong to the classroom and the next year, if he studies, will pass to the next classroom.

I'd like to create a new resource associations
year-classroom-students
using the following URI

> /years/{yearCode}/classrooms/{classroomCode}/students/{studentsId}

Before save new resource I check for yearCode, classroomCode, and studentId.

Which HTTP status code should I send when one of the previous resource is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Once the invalid values are sent in the URL, which is used to locate a resource in the server, in you could return [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4):

> [**6.5.4.  404 Not Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)
>
> The `404` (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did
> not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
> willing to disclose that one exists. [...]

On the other hand, if you want to send the parameters in the request payload, you could consider [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) to indicate that the request entity cannot be processed:

> [**11.2.  422 Unprocessable Entity**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)
>
> The `422` (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> `415` (Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a `400` (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

---

For both situations, the response payload should contain details about the error. Have a look at the [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807).

Comment: so you propose 422 for child reference missing?

Comment: @Konrad If a "child" resource is referenced in the URL and it cannot be located in the server, `404` is the status code to go for. Otherwise, when a "child" resource is referenced in the payload and it cannot be located in the server, `422` is more appropriated.